# Adding chat to a Laravel social media project

Tags: php, laravel, vuex

I am trying to build a social media project with private chat functionality, I am a bit new at this, but with youtube's help I have managed to set most of it up using Laravel, Vuex, Fractal and Axios.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to click on a button on a friends page that will open up a new or friends current chat. Right now, if I click on the button it just goes to the new message form, but the reciever information is not passed through, its the part I am having a hard time figuring out.

I guess to go from

usersidebar.blade.php

```
<div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', ['email' => $user->email]) }}">
        <img class="media-object" alt="" src="">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
            <h3 class="media-heading">{{ $user->getName() }}</h3>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send me a message</button>
</div>
```

to

NewMessageForm.vue

```
<template>
    <form action="#" @submit.prevent="reply">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea cols="95" rows="4" class="form-group" placeholder="Reply" v-model="body"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Reply</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>    
    export default {

    }

</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to show your code. Otherwise mods will close your question.

Comment: Im not really sure what to code to show at this point. A user profile with a button looks like...

from a blade partial, 
<li><a href="">Send {{ $listing->user->first_name }} a message</a></li>

it would to a route page that would look something like

Route::get('/messages/{message}', 'MessageController@show');

to a vue template, 

I dont mean to sound rude, and I will like to share code, but not sure what you would want/need. I thought it was more of a theory type question right now...

Comment: Show everything that might be relevant to your question.

Comment: That is a lot of stuff....

Comment: Well. let's see if i understood your problem. You are having trouble getting the messages from other users? Is that chat working with websockets? Are you saving the messages on some king of database? What should happen when you click on the chat button in some friends page?

Comment: I have messages working, I can manually create them in my database, and use the browser to send a recieve between two users, the chat works.

Instead of manually creating conversations, I want to be able to just click on a friends message me button, and create a conversation that way... or be directed to a conversation we are already in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this logic, for when a user opens a chat box:

1. Fetch the oldest conversations from the database;
2. Create a socket connection to send and receive messages realtime (for this I would recommend you to use [socket.io](https://socket.io/))
3. Save the new messages on the database